# Old Debian packages install sources

Tags: debian, aptitude

I'm trying to install `make` program using aptitude install make in my Debian. Unfortunately I have error :

```
Err http://debian.balt.net lenny/main make 3.81-5 
404 NotFound
```

What I need to do to make things go?

```
My linux version:
2.6.26-2-686 (Debian 2.6.26-22lenny1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error is about your sources, you need to change your repo sources. Now you are asking to http://debian.balt.net about lenny sources and it says that there isn't anyone repo for lenny dist.

You have to look for a new repo and change it in

> vim /etc/apt/sources.list

The standard format is:

> deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2
>   component3
>
> deb-src http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1
>   component2 component3

You have to change the actual repos by some actual, I think this may work right

> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main 
>   deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main
>
> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny-updates main
>   deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny-updates main
>
> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny/updates main 
>   deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny/updates main